# Spring Batch run fine for 1st run, but for 2nd and so on runs... it keeps failing why?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-batch-stream

I am developing a Spring Boot + Spring-Batch example. The very first time I am able to successfully run the code, but for second run it gives me below error.

How can I resolve this?

Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:816) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:797) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:324) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at com.example.XmlFileOutputApplication.main(XmlFileOutputApplication.java:26) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException: A job instance already exists and is complete for parameters={}.  If you want to run this job again, change the parameters.
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.createJobExecution(SimpleJobRepository.java:132) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294) ~[spring-tx-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean$1.invoke(AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean.java:181) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy39.createJobExecution(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:134) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy37.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.execute(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:214) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.executeLocalJobs(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:186) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.launchJobFromProperties(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:172) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.run(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:166) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:813) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    ... 5 common frames omitted

2018-12-08 22:27:41.017  INFO 21172 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter    : Destroy method 'close' on bean with name 'customerItemWriter' threw an exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
2018-12-08 22:27:41.017  INFO 21172 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2018-12-08 22:27:41.017  INFO 21172 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

Customer.java

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Customer {
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String birthdate;
}
```

CustomerRowMapper.java

```
public class CustomerRowMapper implements RowMapper<Customer> {
    @Override
    public Customer mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        return Customer.builder().id(rs.getLong("id"))
                .firstName(rs.getString("firstName"))
                .lastName(rs.getString("lastName"))
                .birthdate(rs.getString("birthdate")).build();
    }
}
```

JobConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
public class JobConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
    
    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
    
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;
    
    @Bean
    public JdbcPagingItemReader<Customer> customerPagingItemReader(){
        // reading database records using JDBC in a paging fashion
        JdbcPagingItemReader<Customer> reader = new JdbcPagingItemReader<>();
        reader.setDataSource(this.dataSource);
        reader.setFetchSize(1000);
        reader.setRowMapper(new CustomerRowMapper());
        
        // Sort Keys
        Map<String, Order> sortKeys = new HashMap<>();
        sortKeys.put("id", Order.ASCENDING);
        
        // MySQL implementation of a PagingQueryProvider using database specific features.
        MySqlPagingQueryProvider queryProvider = new MySqlPagingQueryProvider();
        queryProvider.setSelectClause("id, firstName, lastName, birthdate");
        queryProvider.setFromClause("from customer");
        queryProvider.setSortKeys(sortKeys);
        
        reader.setQueryProvider(queryProvider);
        
        return reader;
    }
    
    
    @Bean
    public StaxEventItemWriter<Customer> customerItemWriter() throws Exception{
        String customerOutputPath = File.createTempFile("customerOutput", ".out").getAbsolutePath();
        System.out.println(">> Output Path = "+customerOutputPath);
        
        Map<String, Class> aliases = new HashMap<>();
        aliases.put("customer", Customer.class);
        
        XStreamMarshaller marshaller = new XStreamMarshaller();
        marshaller.setAliases(aliases);
        
        // StAX and Marshaller for serializing object to XML. 
        StaxEventItemWriter<Customer> writer = new StaxEventItemWriter<>();
        writer.setRootTagName("customers");
        writer.setMarshaller(marshaller);
        writer.setResource(new FileSystemResource(customerOutputPath));
        writer.afterPropertiesSet();
        
        return writer;
    }
    
    
    @Bean
    public Step step1() throws Exception {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .<Customer, Customer>chunk(100)
                .reader(customerPagingItemReader())
                .writer(customerItemWriter())
                .build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public Job job() throws Exception {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("job")
                .start(step1())
                .build();
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.batch.initialize-schema=always
```

XmlFileOutputApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class XmlFileOutputApplication implements CommandLineRunner{
    @Autowired
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @Autowired
    private Job job;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(XmlFileOutputApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
                .addString("JobId", String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .addDate("date", new Date())
                .addLong("time",System.currentTimeMillis()).toJobParameters();
        
        JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);
        System.out.println("STATUS :: "+execution.getStatus());
    }
}
```

[image]

Another image:

[image]

Schema-mysql.sql

```
CREATE TABLE `test`.`customer` (
  `id` MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `firstName` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `lastName` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `birthdate` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
  ) AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Data

```
INSERT INTO `test`.`customer` (`id`, `firstName`, `lastName`, `birthdate`) VALUES ('1', 'John', 'Doe', '10-10-1952 10:10:10');
INSERT INTO `test`.`customer` (`id`, `firstName`, `lastName`, `birthdate`) VALUES ('2', 'Amy', 'Eugene', '05-07-1985 17:10:00');
INSERT INTO `test`.`customer` (`id`, `firstName`, `lastName`, `birthdate`) VALUES ('3', 'Laverne', 'Mann', '11-12-1988 10:10:10');
INSERT INTO `test`.`customer` (`id`, `firstName`, `lastName`, `birthdate`) VALUES ('4', 'Janice', 'Preston', '19-02-1960 10:10:10');
INSERT INTO `test`.`customer` (`id`, `firstName`, `lastName`, `birthdate`) VALUES ('5', 'Pauline', 'Rios', '29-08-1977 10:10:10');
INSERT INTO `test`.`customer` (`id`, `firstName`, `lastName`, `birthdate`) VALUES ('6', 'Perry', 'Burnside', '10-03-1981 10:10:10');
INSERT INTO `test`.`customer` (`id`, `firstName`, `lastName`, `birthdate`) VALUES ('7', 'Todd', 'Kinsey', '14-12-1998 10:10:10');
INSERT INTO `test`.`customer` (`id`, `firstName`, `lastName`, `birthdate`) VALUES ('8', 'Jacqueline', 'Hyde', '20-03-1983 10:10:10');
INSERT INTO `test`.`customer` (`id`, `firstName`, `lastName`, `birthdate`) VALUES ('9', 'Rico', 'Hale', '10-10-2000 10:10:10');
INSERT INTO `test`.`customer` (`id`, `firstName`, `lastName`, `birthdate`) VALUES ('10', 'Samuel', 'Lamm', '11-11-1999 10:10:10');
INSERT INTO `test`.`customer` (`id`, `firstName`, `lastName`, `birthdate`) VALUES ('11', 'Robert', 'Coster', '10-10-1972 10:10:10');
INSERT INTO `test`.`customer` (`id`, `firstName`, `lastName`, `birthdate`) VALUES ('12', 'Tamara', 'Soler', '02-01-1978 10:10:10');
INSERT INTO `test`.`customer` (`id`, `firstName`, `lastName`, `birthdate`) VALUES ('13', 'Justin', 'Kramer', '19-11-1951 10:10:10');
INSERT INTO `test`.`customer` (`id`, `firstName`, `lastName`, `birthdate`) VALUES ('14', 'Andrea', 'Law', '14-10-1959 10:10:10');
INSERT INTO `test`.`customer` (`id`, `firstName`, `lastName`, `birthdate`) VALUES ('15', 'Laura', 'Porter', '12-12-2010 10:10:10');
INSERT INTO `test`.`customer` (`id`, `firstName`, `lastName`, `birthdate`) VALUES ('16', 'Michael', 'Cantu', '11-04-1999 10:10:10');
INSERT INTO `test`.`customer` (`id`, `firstName`, `lastName`, `birthdate`) VALUES ('17', 'Andrew', 'Thomas', '04-05-1967 10:10:10');
INSERT INTO `test`.`customer` (`id`, `firstName`, `lastName`, `birthdate`) VALUES ('18', 'Jose', 'Hannah', '16-09-1950 10:10:10');
INSERT INTO `test`.`customer` (`id`, `firstName`, `lastName`, `birthdate`) VALUES ('19', 'Valerie', 'Hilbert', '13-06-1966 10:10:10');
INSERT INTO `test`.`customer` (`id`, `firstName`, `lastName`, `birthdate`) VALUES ('20', 'Patrick', 'Durham', '12-10-1978 10:10:10');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution mentioned in Spring docs worked for me. I just added one line in application.properties and it stops the batch job execution on startup.

```
spring.batch.job.enabled=false
```